# How to Detect FreeFall in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

While cleaning up my animations in game, I encountered a problem. I have 2 animations, Fall and FreeFall. Everytime my character is in air, the fall animation plays. I'm trying to detect that if I'm free falling (from a very high height), the FreeFall animation will play.

My first attempt was to use this code:
`if (rigidbody.velocity.y < -50f)  { animator.SetBool("isFreeFalling", true }`

The code above wouldn't work. I'm thinking of using raycasts, any thoughts?

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work? Have you tried printing the vertical velocity of your body in the console? What value does it return? Mention all these details in your question

Comment: Is your definition of _"free fall"_ simply falling _"from a very high height"?_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall

Comment: You could shoot a raycast downwards and see the height which player is falling from

Answer (score 0):

Your criterion is based on height, then why should you check velocity?
You should check y position of character relative to may be ground and decide which animation should be played on different heights.

Comment: _"...then why should you check height?"_ - should that read: _"then why **don't** you check height?"_